# how to take backup of riak data

Tags: riak, riak-2i

Does anybody know how to take backup of riak database. So that I can restore it previous point if anything goes wrong. According to Basho's site, they have suggested that Rsync is the best strategy. I can copy database files by Rsync , but I am unable to link it with newly created node in riak cluster. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The best advice you will get on backing up Riak is located here: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/cluster-operations/backing-up/

Point-in-time backups are possible but challenging due to the nature of how your data is distributed around nodes and the built in repair mechanisms the Riak employs when nodes leave and return to the cluster. If you want to restore a cluster to a state that it was in at a given point-in-time then all nodes need to get restored back to that state at the same time which likely means downtime (which Riak is designed to avoid).

As to why you are unable to restore the node with a backup you made you don't provide enough information to determine why the restoration steps in the documentation (http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/cluster-operations/backing-up/#restoring-a-node) aren't working for you.